# How to detect the OS from a Bash script?

Tags: bash, os-detection

I would like to keep my `.bashrc` and `.bash_login` files in version control so that I can use them between all the computers I use. The problem is I have some OS specific aliases so I was looking for a way to determine if the script is running on Mac OS X, Linux or [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

What is the proper way to detect the operating system in a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script?

Comment: Have you ever considered sharing your configs? I was looking to get the same kind of setup :)

Comment: @sorin I know it's an old comment, but if you're still curious, I've been building [ProfileGem](http://hg.mwdiamond.com/profilegem) which lets you configure pluggable bash environments for all your machines.

Comment: @dimo414 profilegem seems to have been moved here https://bitbucket.org/dimo414/profilegem. As far as sharing bash configs in general, try some of these dotfiles projects: https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=dotfiles&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @mahemoff thanks for the updated link, sorry I can't edit my comment.  I'd welcome feedback or bugs if you're experimenting with ProfileGem!

Comment: Alas BitBucket is turning down Mercurial support, so I have to update my link again :( https://github.com/dimo414/ProfileGem is the new home.

Comment: For those of you looking for a "cross-platform solution" (as in one which works on both WSL/macOS/Linux, check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706298/8604951

Answer (score 892, accepted):

I think the following should work. I'm not sure about `win32` though.

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu"* ]]; then
        # ...
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
        # Mac OSX
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "cygwin" ]]; then
        # POSIX compatibility layer and Linux environment emulation for Windows
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "msys" ]]; then
        # Lightweight shell and GNU utilities compiled for Windows (part of MinGW)
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "win32" ]]; then
        # I'm not sure this can happen.
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "freebsd"* ]]; then
        # ...
else
        # Unknown.
fi
```

Comment: On Windows, you will get `msys` for Git Bash/msysGit, and `cygwin` for Cygwin

Comment: This answer including how to detect for Windows is good. I'm also using Mingw32 and it comes up as `msys`

Comment: Interesting.. Mac OSX would still give 'darwin'.

Comment: My OSX Yosemit (10.10.5) has no $OSTYPE.

Comment: OS X El Capitan: `$ echo $OSTYPE` => `darwin15`

Comment: Something that tripped me up, when you replace the comment with a command - make sure to end with with `;`.

Comment: When I add a command like `source somefile ; `, I get `syntax error near unexpected token elif`.

Comment: Anybody have an idea on how to distinguish between WSL and vanilla Linux? WSL is technically linux so uname and OSTYPE don't work.

Comment: @DavidA.French `grep Microsoft /proc/version` should work, according to https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/423.

Comment: Thanks @Alcaro I ended up using `UNAMECHECK=$(uname -a);
if [[ $UNAMECHECK == *"Microsoft"* ]]`

Comment: linux-android? for Termux

Comment: @Penn My Android terminal doesn't use BASH by default (not sure why). But after logging into the BASH shell, OSTYPE was set to "android-eabi". This terminal is strange. I think Termux uses BASH or another popular shell, so OSTYPE is probably set in it. I believe the correct code would be `elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "android"* ]]; then`.

Comment: @AntumDeluge I actually encountered this behaviour too. I tried exactly the same fix as you but with [ not [[, hence globbing didn't work so I ended up using grep (because I need to support non-bash systems)

Comment: Nice but I would use a switch case here rather than the if/else sequence.

Comment: The value is `msys` in MSYS2 as well.

Comment: `"linux-gnu"` should be `"linux-gnu"*`. As far I tested, Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi 4 and Raspbian Buster on Raspberry Pi 3 returns "linux-gnueabihf".

Comment: WSL also returns `linux-gnu`. Check `/proc/version` for string `"Microsoft"` to detect WSL (via: `if grep -q -i microsoft /proc/version; then`)

Comment: Latest macos on Github Actions gives "darwin19" :/

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work in docker

Comment: I found a [useful list](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/issues/433) of possible `$OSTYPE` values.

Answer (score 320):

For my .bashrc, I use the following code:

```
platform='unknown'
unamestr=$(uname)
if [[ "$unamestr" == 'Linux' ]]; then
   platform='linux'
elif [[ "$unamestr" == 'FreeBSD' ]]; then
   platform='freebsd'
fi
```

Then I do somethings like:

```
if [[ $platform == 'linux' ]]; then
   alias ls='ls --color=auto'
elif [[ $platform == 'freebsd' ]]; then
   alias ls='ls -G'
fi
```

It's ugly, but it works. You may use `case` instead of `if` if you prefer.

Comment: Why do you set platform from unamestr, instead of just using unamestr?

Comment: I don't know if uname will always give me the same thing, so I make myself independant of its value.

Comment: While maybe not the most generic way, this is what I wound up using, so it gets my vote.  Thanks Nic.

Comment: Don't use backticks, use the newer clearer syntax: "unamestr = $(uname)".

Comment: From a quick glance, the backticks could resemble a string.

Comment: @david-winiecki Because if you need to nest commands e.g. $(command-1 $(command-2))

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to do: `platform="$(uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"` and then definitely handle in a case? It just seems weird to hardcode a dependency on very specific output.

Comment: to detect a mac if you execute this in the terminal you will get darwin. 
echo `uname`
Darwin

Comment: @uwind or use whatever you like best and quit preaching. there's no one single best way.

Comment: Why do you have to type '[[' ']]' ? Why wouldn't '[' ']' work?

Answer (score 304):

The [bash manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) says that the variable **`OSTYPE`** stores the name of the operating system:

> `OSTYPE` Automatically set to a string that describes the operating system on which bash is executing.   The  default  is  system-
> dependent.

It is set to `linux-gnu` here.

Comment: Also, $OSTYPE is 'darwin9.0' on my mac (Leopard) and 'cygwin' under Cygwin.

Comment: In Debian Testing, $OSTYPE also contains linux-gnu.

Comment: $OSTYPE is darwin10.0 on SnowLeopard. WTF with the version appended? Means a simple case statement won't work.

Comment: It's not that big of a deal to remove it: `os=${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}`

Comment: `case $OSTYPE in darwin*) echo I am a Mac ;; esac`

Comment: darwin11 on Lion, for reference.

Comment: @tripleee or for people that are more comfortable with "if" syntax:
`if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then echo I am a Mac;fi`

Comment: My OSX Yosemit (10.10.5) has no $OSTYPE.

Comment: @Marboni strange, I have the same OS version and my `$OSTYPE` is `darwin14`.

Comment: Appears to be a non POSIX Bash extension BTW, [determined via grepping dowloaded POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453993/is-there-a-listing-of-the-posix-api-functions/45832939#45832939).

Comment: Nice. However doesnt help when WSL and WSL2 on windows also report the same value and you need to know the difference someteims. Posted my own answer how I solved thi.s

Answer (score 266):

#### `$OSTYPE`

You can simply use pre-defined `$OSTYPE` variable e.g.:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
  solaris*) echo "SOLARIS" ;;
  darwin*)  echo "OSX" ;; 
  linux*)   echo "LINUX" ;;
  bsd*)     echo "BSD" ;;
  msys*)    echo "WINDOWS" ;;
  cygwin*)  echo "ALSO WINDOWS" ;;
  *)        echo "unknown: $OSTYPE" ;;
esac
```

However it's [not recognized by the older shells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23424783/55075) (such as [*Bourne shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)).

---

#### [`uname`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uname)

Another method is to detect platform based on `uname` command.

See the following script (ready to include in .bashrc):

```
# Detect the platform (similar to $OSTYPE)
OS="`uname`"
case $OS in
  'Linux')
    OS='Linux'
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    ;;
  'FreeBSD')
    OS='FreeBSD'
    alias ls='ls -G'
    ;;
  'WindowsNT')
    OS='Windows'
    ;;
  'Darwin') 
    OS='Mac'
    ;;
  'SunOS')
    OS='Solaris'
    ;;
  'AIX') ;;
  *) ;;
esac
```

[You can find some practical example in my `.bashrc`](https://github.com/kenorb/dotfiles).

---

Here is similar version used on [Travis CI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/061cd364c38a07c8908b420b9dd134d86b537b01/lib/travis/build/bash/travis_setup_env.bash):

```
case $(uname | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in
  linux*)
    export TRAVIS_OS_NAME=linux
    ;;
  darwin*)
    export TRAVIS_OS_NAME=osx
    ;;
  msys*)
    export TRAVIS_OS_NAME=windows
    ;;
  *)
    export TRAVIS_OS_NAME=notset
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: The $OSTYPE check is missing a branch for cygwin, which would indicate a windows machine.  The uname check would not work properly either, on cygwin uname returns "CYGWIN_NT-10.0" and on MinGW uname returns "MINGW64_NT-10.0".

Comment: alias ls='/bin/ls -G' is actually the safe option, in the context of OS-based fags
see https://superuser.com/a/1299969/84662

Comment: I suggest using `uname`, Oracle have glossed convention and put a free version string with their `OSTYPE ==>  solaris2.11`.  `uname` is a little cleaner and less work to do.

Answer (score 48):

Detecting **operating system and CPU type** is not so easy to do *portably*.  I have a `sh` script of about 100 lines that works across a very wide variety of Unix platforms: any system I have used since 1988.

The key elements are

- `uname -p` is **processor type** but is usually `unknown` on modern Unix platforms.
- `uname -m` will give the "machine hardware name" on some Unix systems.
- `/bin/arch`, if it exists, will usually give the type of processor.
- `uname` with no arguments will name the operating system.

Eventually you will have to think about the distinctions between platforms and **how fine you want to make them.**  For example, just to keep things simple, I treat `i386` through `i686` , any "`Pentium*`" and any "`AMD*Athlon*`" all as `x86`.

My `~/.profile` runs an a script at startup which sets one variable to a string indicating the combination of CPU and operating system.  I have platform-specific `bin`, `man`, `lib`, and `include` directories that get set up based on that.  Then I set a boatload of environment variables.  So for example, a shell script to reformat mail can call, e.g., `$LIB/mailfmt` which is a platform-specific executable binary.

**If you want to cut corners**, `uname -m` and plain `uname` will tell you what you want to know on many platforms.  Add other stuff when you need it.  (And use `case`, not nested `if`!)

Comment: According to *[uname Command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/uname.htm)*, uname without a parameter is equivalent to using the "-s" parameter: "-s Displays the system name. This flag is on by default.". To be explicit one could use "uname -s" instead of "uname". (Elaborated somewhat in *[an answer to 'Shell output help'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/shell-output-help/32052#32052)*)

Comment: Do you have a link to a github git or pastebin with this 100 script for reliably detecting OS and processor architecture?

Comment: @AndrewDeAndrade I'm ashamed to expose this code to the public. http://pastebin.com/J66Lj6wf

Comment: so how about `uname -s`?

Answer (score 43):

I recommend to use this complete bash code

```
lowercase(){
    echo "$1" | sed "y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/"
}

OS=`lowercase \`uname\``
KERNEL=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`

if [ "{$OS}" == "windowsnt" ]; then
    OS=windows
elif [ "{$OS}" == "darwin" ]; then
    OS=mac
else
    OS=`uname`
    if [ "${OS}" = "SunOS" ] ; then
        OS=Solaris
        ARCH=`uname -p`
        OSSTR="${OS} ${REV}(${ARCH} `uname -v`)"
    elif [ "${OS}" = "AIX" ] ; then
        OSSTR="${OS} `oslevel` (`oslevel -r`)"
    elif [ "${OS}" = "Linux" ] ; then
        if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
            DistroBasedOn='RedHat'
            DIST=`cat /etc/redhat-release |sed s/\ release.*//`
            PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
            REV=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
        elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ] ; then
            DistroBasedOn='SuSe'
            PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' '| sed s/VERSION.*//`
            REV=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*=\ //`
        elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ] ; then
            DistroBasedOn='Mandrake'
            PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
            REV=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
        elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ] ; then
            DistroBasedOn='Debian'
            DIST=`cat /etc/lsb-release | grep '^DISTRIB_ID' | awk -F=  '{ print $2 }'`
            PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/lsb-release | grep '^DISTRIB_CODENAME' | awk -F=  '{ print $2 }'`
            REV=`cat /etc/lsb-release | grep '^DISTRIB_RELEASE' | awk -F=  '{ print $2 }'`
        fi
        if [ -f /etc/UnitedLinux-release ] ; then
            DIST="${DIST}[`cat /etc/UnitedLinux-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/VERSION.*//`]"
        fi
        OS=`lowercase $OS`
        DistroBasedOn=`lowercase $DistroBasedOn`
        readonly OS
        readonly DIST
        readonly DistroBasedOn
        readonly PSUEDONAME
        readonly REV
        readonly KERNEL
        readonly MACH
    fi

fi
echo $OS
echo $KERNEL
echo $MACH
```

more examples examples here: https://github.com/coto/server-easy-install/blob/master/lib/core.sh

Comment: You left out the lowercase function, I updated your answer for you.

Comment: Once you know it's Linux, if you're just poking around (not trying to automate finding out) it seems like easiest move is to just `ls /etc` and look for "blah-release" - whatever blah is, that's the Linux OS - CentOS, Ubuntu, etc

Comment: I edited because some of the references to OS variable were written as "{$OS}" I changed them to "${OS}" that's the right way, I tested it

Comment: would you consider to add "echo ${OS}" at the very end of the script?

Comment: This is a lot of work for a big mystery at the end (no information printed). I second that it needs `echo $OS` at the end.

Comment: I prefer using `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` over the lengthy sed pattern in the lowercase function.

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest avoiding some of these answers. Don't forget that you can choose other forms of string comparison, which would clear up most of the variations, or ugly code offered.

One such solution would be a simple check, such as:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^darwin ]]; then
```

Which has the added benefit of matching any version of Darwin, despite it's version suffix. This also works for any variations of `Linux` one may expect.

You can see some additional examples within my dotfiles [here](https://github.com/akiva/dotfiles)

Comment: Link isn't working..

Answer (score 14):

```
uname
```

or

```
uname -a
```

if you want more information

Answer (score 14):

This is what I use if anyone is interested in detecting WSL vs WSL version 2 as well.
This works in ZSH as well as BASH.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unameOut=$(uname -a)
case "${unameOut}" in
    *Microsoft*)     OS="WSL";; #must be first since Windows subsystem for linux will have Linux in the name too
    *microsoft*)     OS="WSL2";; #WARNING: My v2 uses ubuntu 20.4 at the moment slightly different name may not always work
    Linux*)     OS="Linux";;
    Darwin*)    OS="Mac";;
    CYGWIN*)    OS="Cygwin";;
    MINGW*)     OS="Windows";;
    *Msys)     OS="Windows";;
    *)          OS="UNKNOWN:${unameOut}"
esac

echo ${OS};
```

Update: I also added this to my script for detecting M1 vs a normal Mac.

```
if [[ ${OS} == "Mac" ]] && sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string | grep -q 'Apple M1'; then
    OS="MacM1"
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

Try using "uname". For example, in Linux: "uname -a".

According to the manual page, uname conforms to SVr4 and POSIX, so it should be available on Mac OS X and [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) too, but I can't confirm that.

BTW: $OSTYPE is also set to `linux-gnu` here :)

Comment: Without parameters, uname prints 'Darwin' on Mac OS X (leopard). With -a it prints a whole lot of extra information (kernel version, architecture and something else I cannot decipher). I cannot test on cygwin

Answer (score 11):

In bash, use `$OSTYPE` and `$HOSTTYPE`, as documented; this is what I do.  If that is not enough, and if even `uname` or `uname -a` (or other appropriate options) does not give enough information, there’s always the [config.guess](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD) script from the GNU project, made exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 11):

Below it's an approach to detect Debian and RedHat based **Linux OS** making use of the ***/etc/lsb-release*** and ***/etc/os-release*** (depending on the Linux flavor you're using) and take a simple action based on it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

YUM_PACKAGE_NAME="python python-devl python-pip openssl-devel"
DEB_PACKAGE_NAME="python2.7 python-dev python-pip libssl-dev"

 if cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep CentOS; then
    echo "==============================================="
    echo "Installing packages $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME on CentOS"
    echo "==============================================="
    yum install -y $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Red; then
    echo "==============================================="
    echo "Installing packages $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME on RedHat"
    echo "==============================================="
    yum install -y $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Fedora; then
    echo "================================================"
    echo "Installing packages $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME on Fedorea"
    echo "================================================"
    yum install -y $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Ubuntu; then
    echo "==============================================="
    echo "Installing packages $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME on Ubuntu"
    echo "==============================================="
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Debian ; then
    echo "==============================================="
    echo "Installing packages $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME on Debian"
    echo "==============================================="
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Mint ; then
    echo "============================================="
    echo "Installing packages $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME on Mint"
    echo "============================================="
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | grep Knoppix ; then
    echo "================================================="
    echo "Installing packages $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME on Kanoppix"
    echo "================================================="
    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
 else
    echo "OS NOT DETECTED, couldn't install package $PACKAGE"
    exit 1;
 fi

exit 0
```

**Output example** for **Ubuntu Linux:**

```
delivery@delivery-E5450$ sudo sh detect_os.sh
[sudo] password for delivery: 
NAME="Ubuntu"
===============================================
Installing packages python2.7 python-dev python-pip libssl-dev on Ubuntu
===============================================
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [916 B]                          
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1.189 B] 
...
```

Answer (score 10):

I wrote these sugars in my `.bashrc`:

```
if_os () { [[ $OSTYPE == *$1* ]]; }
if_nix () { 
    case "$OSTYPE" in
        *linux*|*hurd*|*msys*|*cygwin*|*sua*|*interix*) sys="gnu";;
        *bsd*|*darwin*) sys="bsd";;
        *sunos*|*solaris*|*indiana*|*illumos*|*smartos*) sys="sun";;
    esac
    [[ "${sys}" == "$1" ]];
}
```

So I can do stuff like:

```
if_nix gnu && alias ls='ls --color=auto' && export LS_COLORS="..."
if_nix bsd && export CLICOLORS=on && export LSCOLORS="..."
if_os linux && alias psg="ps -FA | grep" #alternative to pgrep
if_nix bsd && alias psg="ps -alwx | grep -i" #alternative to pgrep
if_os darwin && alias finder="open -R"
```

Comment: BTW, these 9 lines work on any Bash running on most anything. No shellouts and works with almost any style of personal .bashrc (big nested if/case trees or lots of random aliases). IMO, beats the pants off every answer above it.

Comment: So far, closest to complete for including Cygwin and other BSD (basically compilation of popular *NIX)

Comment: Complete for userlands that are relevant today and run Bash. AIX/HP-UX/IRIX/OpenVMS users could chime in.
The new Windows Subsystem for Linux runs a stock amd64 Ubuntu install so it should return true for both  `if_nix gnu` & `if_os linux`.

Comment: @kfix yes that's right, the win 10 bash subsystem outputs "linux-gnu" for ```echo $OSTYPE```. To detect win 10 bash subsystem specifically, the only solution i've found was to check for "Microsoft" in ```/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following:

```
OS=$(uname -s)
```

then you can use OS variable in your script.

Comment: can you explain how `uname -s` is different than `uname`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills -s, --kernel-name        print the kernel name

Comment: @AlexanderMills  on macos using bash `man uname` 

`"If no options are specified, uname prints the  operating system name as if the -s option had been specified."`

Answer (score 8):

I wrote [a personal Bash library and scripting framework](http://www.gnu.org/software/shtool/) that uses [GNU shtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/shtool/) to do a rather accurate platform detection.

GNU shtool is a very portable set of scripts that contains, among other useful things, the 'shtool platform' command. Here is the output of:

```
shtool platform -v -F "%sc (%ac) %st (%at) %sp (%ap)"
```

on a few different machines:

```
Mac OS X Leopard: 
    4.4BSD/Mach3.0 (iX86) Apple Darwin 9.6.0 (i386) Apple Mac OS X 10.5.6 (iX86)

Ubuntu Jaunty server:
    LSB (iX86) GNU/Linux 2.9/2.6 (i686) Ubuntu 9.04 (iX86)

Debian Lenny:
    LSB (iX86) GNU/Linux 2.7/2.6 (i686) Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 (iX86)
```

This produces pretty satisfactory results, as you can see. GNU shtool is a little slow, so I actually store and update the platform identification in a file on the system that my scripts call. It's my framework, so that works for me, but your mileage may vary.

Now, you'll have to find a way to package shtool with your scripts, but it's not a hard exercise. You can always fall back on uname output, also.

EDIT:

I missed the post by Teddy about `config.guess` (somehow). These are very similar scripts, but not the same. I personally use shtool for other uses as well, and it has been working quite well for me.

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
DISTRO=$(cat /etc/*-release | grep -w NAME | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d '"')
echo "Determined platform: $DISTRO"
```

Comment: On macOS I get `cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory`

Comment: @csexton really, i'm getting the same: `zsh: no matches found: /etc/*release` -- this will work only for linux systems, I suppose...

Comment: This answer works for Linux, only, for sure. But other answers are capable of detecting Linux in opposition to other systems only. This basic discovery isn't helping at all for discovering particular Linux distribution is quite as essential as distinguishing between FreeBSD and Darwin.

Comment: okay, when I posted this comment, there was no need to perform this against multiple platforms, thus I tried to show how to see your Linux distro :)

Comment: This pipe symbol is used so beautifully!

Answer (score 7):

This should be safe to use on all distros.

```
$ cat /etc/*release
```

This produces something like this.

```
     DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
     DISTRIB_RELEASE=17
     DISTRIB_CODENAME=qiana
     DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
     NAME="Ubuntu"
     VERSION="14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
     ID=ubuntu
     ID_LIKE=debian
     PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
     VERSION_ID="14.04"
     HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
     SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
     BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Extract/assign to variables as you wish

Note: On some setups. This may also give you some errors that you can ignore.

```
     cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

Comment: Note: on CentOS, this gives `[user@host ~]$ cat /etc/*release
    CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
    CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
    CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`

Comment: Yes, the output I posted was an example, from one of my laptops, not static content you see everywhere.

Comment: Just added that so nobody would think the result is always in the same form :)

Comment: +1 I'm using set -e at the beginning of the script (Thus this solution isn't working http://www.doxer.org/linux-shell-centos-debian-ostype/). And other solutions don't specifically CentOS. But I found this reference which proved this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92212

Comment: does not work for Mac:
`cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory`

Comment: Got another one: Debian 6 doesn't have `/etc/debian_release`, but `/etc/debian_version`

Comment: The OP asked for OS such as OSX and Cygwin, this won't work on such OS.  Answers resembling the env var $OSTYPE or $(uname -a) is the way it must be done

Comment: Does not work on cygwin: ```cat: '/etc/*release': No such file or directory```

Comment: I clearly said distros. Mac OS X, cygwin are not distros. Mac OSX FreeBSD/BSD based, and cygwin is an environment. So I don't see why some are confused. 
And yes, works on debian too. The output may different per distro, but the information can be easily extracted.

Answer (score 5):

You can use following if clause and expand it as needed:

```sh
if [ "${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}" == "darwin" ]
then
    aminute_ago="-v-1M"
elif  [ "${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}" == "linux-gnu" ]
then
    aminute_ago="-d \"1 minute ago\""
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I tend to keep my .bashrc and .bash_alias on a file share that all platforms can access. This is how I conquer the problem in my .bash_alias:

```
if [[ -f (name of share)/.bash_alias_$(uname) ]]; then
    . (name of share)/.bash_alias_$(uname)
fi
```

And I have for example a .bash_alias_Linux with:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

This way I keep platform specific and portable code separate, you can do the same for .bashrc

Answer (score 3):

I tried the above messages across a few Linux distros and found the following to work best for me.  It’s a short, concise exact word answer that works for Bash on Windows as well.

```
OS=$(cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | tr -d 'NAME="') #$ echo $OS # Ubuntu
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Seems nice and terse for most linux systems, but unfortunately this will result in an error on macOS. Perhaps this is more "detect the linux distribution flavor from Bash

Comment: @csexton `OS=$( ([[ -f /etc/*release ]] && cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | tr -d 'NAME="') || echo "Unknown" )` this will work without throwing errors.

Comment: Actually, here is a correct way `OS=$( $(compgen -G "/etc/*release" > /dev/null) && cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | tr -d 'NAME="')  || $( echo "${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}")`

Comment: @Kuzeko I unfortunately still get errors running this on macOS.

Comment: Just an update to @Kuzeko's command to stop it erroring.... `OS=$( $(compgen -G "/etc/*release" > /dev/null) && cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | tr -d 'NAME="' || echo "${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}")`

Comment: Why `compgen`  exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

This checks a bunch of `known` files to identfy if the linux distro is Debian or Ubunu, then it defaults to the `$OSTYPE` variable.

```
os='Unknown'
unamestr="${OSTYPE//[0-9.]/}"
os=$( compgen -G "/etc/*release" > /dev/null  && cat /etc/*release | grep ^NAME | tr -d 'NAME="'  ||  echo "$unamestr")

echo "$os"
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing the following helped perform the check correctly for ubuntu:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^linux ]]; then
    sudo apt-get install <some-package>
fi
```

Comment: What about other Linux systems that don't use apt-get?

Comment: ubuntu is a distribution, not a operating system class.