# Proper way of printing out an error message

Tags: bash

Is this line the best way to print out an error message in Bash?

```
echo 'Error: banana' >&2
```

I need to update tens of Bash scripts which use all different ways of logging errors and I might as well choose the "right" way to do this and adhere to a standard as I do it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On linux, I'd prefer to say

```
echo "Some error message" >> /dev/stderr
```

This will effectively do the same, of course, since `/dev/stderr` symlinks to `/proc/$PID/fd/2`

Answer (score 15):

at the beginning of my bash-scripts i usually define some functions like:

```
error() {
  echo "$@" 1>&2
}

fail() {
  error "$@"
  exit 1
}
```

which comes quite handy for outputting deadly and ordinary errors.
you could move this snippet into a separate file and `source` that from your all of your bash-scripts with something like:

```
. /usr/local/lib/snippets/error_handling.sh
```

so whenever you decide you need a better way to deal with error messages (e.g. sending critical errors to syslog), you can do so by changing the behaviour for all scripts in one go.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same. Good idea to centralise logging. Would need an elegant double-inclusion guard not to source this bag of utilities twice.