# How to print on stderr without using /dev/stderr

Tags: linux, command-line

How can a linux command script print warnings or error messages without using `>/dev/stderr` each time?

This should be simple but I don't get it.

Can you post a simple example?

Comment: Why the thumbs down? I don't really understand where all the hate comes from, I thought this was a space to ask questions

Comment: Don't know about "hate", but this doesn't look like a programming question to me. Unix usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print to standard error, use a command that writes to standard output (like `echo` or `printf`) and redirect the output to file descriptor 2.

```
echo "This goes to standard output"
echo "This goes to standard error" >&2
```

This is the most common use of the file descriptor duplication operator, which makes the descriptor indicated by the preceding number (or 1 if omitted) a copy of the descriptor indicated by the following number.

Comment: Thanks friend, I don't know why understanding this std stuff has been so hard for me, even though it seems pretty straight forward

Comment: File descriptor handling is one of the trickiest aspects of shell scripting, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Every unix process always has three open file descriptors when the process starts.

0 is stdin

1 is stdout

2 is stderr

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html