# Separating stdout and stderr in Tcl drops all but last line of stderr

Tags: tcl, stdout, stderr

I'm not a Tcl programmer, but I need to modify a Tcl script that invokes an external command and tries to separate `stdout` and `stderr`.  The following is a minimal example of how the script currently does this.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh8.4

set pipe [open "|cmd" r]
while {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {puts $line}
catch "close $pipe" errorMsg
puts "$errorMsg"
```

Here, `cmd` is a an external command, and for the sake of this example, I will replace it with the following shell script.  (I'm working on a Linux machine, but you can modify this to write to `stdout` and `stderr` however is appropriate for your system.)

```
#!/bin/sh -f
echo "A" > /dev/stdout
echo "B" > /dev/stdout
echo "C" > /dev/stderr
echo "D" > /dev/stderr
```

When I execute `cmd`, I get the following four lines as expected:

```
 % ./cmd
A
B
C
D
```

However, when I execute my Tcl script, I get:

```
 % ./test.tcl
A
B
D
```

This is an example of a more general phenomenon, which is that `catch` seems to swallow all but the last line of `stderr`.

To me, the "obvious" way to approach this is to try to mimic what is happening with `stdout`, which obviously works and prints all lines of the output.  However, the current implementation is based on getting a Tcl channel by using `open "|cmd"`, which requires running an external command.  I can't figure out how to create a channel without opening an external command, and even if I could figure that out, there are subsequent issues with this approach.  (How do I get the output of `close` into the channel?  And if I need to open a new channel to get the output of each channel I am closing, then wouldn't I need an infinite number of channels?)

If anyone has any idea why `errorMsg` drops the initial lines or another approach that does not suffer from this problem, please let me know.

I know that this will come up, so I will say in advance that switching to Tcl 8.5 is probably not an option for me in the short term, since I do not control the environment in which this script is run.

Comment: Interestingly, it works as expected if you change the last line of your cmd script to `echo "D" >> /dev/stderr`.

Comment: @SchelteBron That's fascinating but somewhat bizarre, since I didn't think that the difference between `>` and `>>` mattered for `stdout` and `stderr`.  This suggests that I may be able to fix the behavior by changing `cmd` rather than the Tcl script, which in my case is actually easier for me.

Comment: I'm reading a bit more about how this works, and it's possible that this is a case of an interesting interaction between how the unix filesystem treats file descriptors for `stderr` with how Tcl stores the file descriptor.

Comment: This is not related to Tcl, but rather Bash. See the discussions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990414/echo-that-outputs-to-stderr.

Comment: @mrcalvin For reasons that I do not control, the tool `cmd` actually has to be in `csh`, not `bash`, and this answer does not apply.  Since I only need this to work on a particular Linux platform, redirecting to `/dev/stderr` is a good solution for the shell side of things.  But I understand your point.  The ultimate reason is because `> /dev/stderr` replaces the file descriptor for `stderr` with another one, and (unlike the terminal) Tcl doesn't automatically figure this out.  As SchelteBron pointed out, this can be fixed using `>> /dev/stderr` where applicable.

Comment: Well, then you should change your cmd example to use `csh`, actually. Still, it remains a problem of the executed shell scripts, not Tcl related.

Comment: @mrcalvin Sure, when I posted the question, I didn't think that was relevant.  I was only explaining to you after the fact that I can't use `>&2 echo`.

Comment: So, you might want to update the question (`csh`) and provide a self-answer.

Comment: @mrcalvin 1. The code I presented is completely equivalent using `csh` and `sh`.  The only reason that `csh` came up at all is because you suggested a different syntax (rather than a different *operation*) in the shell script, which is entirely irrelevant to the question.  2. I am not confident enough in my understanding of the underlying mechanics of the filesystem to provide a definitive answer, since I am by no means an expert on this.  (In the short term future, I will just hold out hope that someone will post a link to a clear explanation.)