# check if argument is a valid date in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash shell script in Linux, this program will accept a date (mm-dd-yyyy) as a parameter. I am wondering if there is a simply way to check if the date is valid? is there an operator and I can just use test to check?

Comment: Obligatory: [ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check with `date -d "datestring"`

So `date -d "12/31/2012"` is valid, but using hyphens, e.g. `date -d "12-31-2012"`, is not valid for `date`.

You can also use words: `date -d 'yesterday'` or `date -d '1 week ago'` are both valid.

Comment: Bash doesn't care, it's `date` that complains about the hyphens.

Comment: I just tried with slashes and backward slashes (bash .4.2.2, date gnu coreutils 8,4) and it happily accepts both without hyphens.

Answer (score 12):

You can extract the day, month, and year values from the input date value MM-DD-YYYY and validate it as the unambiguous (ISO) format YYYY-MM-DD instead (you can validate a DD-MM-YYY formatted date as "correct" using date, e.g. 25-12-2010, but it is not a valid MM-DD-YYY date, hence the need to change the date format first)

---

#### A valid date in the correct format is OK

30th November 2005 is valid:

```
$ DATE=11-30-2005; d=${DATE:3:2}; m=${DATE:0:2}; Y=${DATE:6:4}; echo "year=$Y, month=$m, day=$d"; if date -d "$Y-$m-$d" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
year=2005, month=11, day=30  
VALID

$ DATE=11-30-2005; if date -d "${DATE:6:4}-${DATE:0:2}-${DATE:3:2}" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
VALID
```

---

#### An invalid date in the correct format is NOT OK

31st November 2005 does not validate:

```
$ DATE=11-31-2005; d=${DATE:3:2}; m=${DATE:0:2}; Y=${DATE:6:4}; echo "year=$Y, month=$m, day=$d"; if date -d "$Y-$m-$d" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
year=2005, month=11, day=31  
INVALID

$ DATE=11-31-2005; if date -d "${DATE:6:4}-${DATE:0:2}-${DATE:3:2}" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
INVALID
```

---

#### A valid date in the incorrect format is NOT OK

20th April 1979 in DD-MM-YYYY format does not validate as a MM-DD-YYYY date:

```
$ DATE=20-04-1979; d=${DATE:3:2}; m=${DATE:0:2}; Y=${DATE:6:4}; echo "year=$Y, month=$m, day=$d"; if date -d "$Y-$m-$d" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
year=1979, month=20, day=04  
INVALID

$ DATE=20-04-1979; if date -d "${DATE:6:4}-${DATE:0:2}-${DATE:3:2}" &> /dev/null; then echo VALID; else echo INVALID; fi
INVALID
```

---

#### Alternate simpler method: use BASH variable string replace hyphens to slashes

```
$ DATE="04-30-2005"; [[ $(date -d "${DATE//-/\/}" 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo VALID || echo INVALID
VALID

$ DATE="04-31-2005"; [[ $(date -d "${DATE//-/\/}" 2> /dev/null) ]] && echo VALID || echo INVALID
INVALID
```

Comment: I know it's been long time since you posted this answer but how do I modified your condition so that it checks "if not valid" instead of "if valid"

Comment: Like many other languages, you use the "!" as a NOT operator, and then change your `then` and `else` to suit, e.g.
```DATE=20-04-1979; d=${DATE:3:2}; m=${DATE:0:2}; Y=${DATE:6:4}; echo "year=$Y, month=$m, day=$d"; if ! date -d "$Y-$m-$d" &> /dev/null; then echo INVALID; fi```

Answer (score 9):

For script use, I kept it as simple as I could. Testing the date value with the date function then checking the exit code of the process.

```
date -d "02/01/2000" 2>: 1>:; echo $?
```

This will redirect the standard in and standard error to null `:` and using echo to return the exit code with `$?` allows me to check for 0=good date and 1=bad date.

Comment: I would not output date to create a file called ":". I'd clean it up bit... date -d "11/31/2018" > /dev/null 2>&1, which will return 1 (false). change the 31 for 30 and the return is 0 (true).

Answer (score 5):

For validation of YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601) dates on OSX in the BASH shell, the following approach validates both the format and the date.

```
isYYYYMMDDdate() {
  [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]] && [[ "$1" == $(date -r $(date -j -f "%Y-%m-%d" "$1" "+%s") '+%Y-%m-%d') ]] &> /dev/null; echo "$?"
}
```

1. It first uses a regular expression match to check the format.
2. Then, it converts the date to epoch time and then back to a date.
3. If the original and twice-converted dates match, then it is valid.

Test a valid date: 2005-11-30

```
$ isYYYYMMDDdate 2005-11-30
0
```

Test an invalid date: 2005-11-31

```
$ isYYYYMMDDdate 2005-11-31
1
```

Test a valid date formatted incorrectly: 1979-20-04

```
$ isYYYYMMDDdate 1979-20-04
1
```

Answer (score 4):

The following worked well for me.  Many thanks to my co-worker, Tyler Chamberlain, for the OSX solution.

```
# Validate a given date/time in Bash on either Linux or Mac (OSX).

# Expected date/time format (in quotes from the command line):  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
# Example(s):  ./this_script "2012-02-29 13:00:00"   # IS valid
#              ./this_script "2013-02-29 13:00:00"   # Is NOT valid

START_DATETIME=$1

function report_error_and_exit
{
   local MSG=$1
   echo "$MSG" >&2
   exit 1
}

# We can use OSTYPE to determine what OS we're running on.
# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script

# Determine whether the given START_DATETIME is valid.
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]
then
   # Validate the date on a Linux machine (Redhat or Debian).  On Linux, this is 
   # as easy as adding one minute and checking the return code.  If one minute 
   # cannot be added, then the starting value is not a valid date/time.
   date -d "$START_DATETIME UTC + 1 min" +"%F %T" &> /dev/null
   test $? -eq 0 || report_error_and_exit "'$START_DATETIME' is not a valid date/time value. $OSTYPE"
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]
then
   # Validate the date on a Mac (OSX).  This is done by adding and subtracting
   # one minute from the given date/time.  If the resulting date/time string is identical 
   # to the given date/time string, then the given date/time is valid.  If not, then the
   # given date/time is invalid.
   TEST_DATETIME=$(date -v+1M -v-1M -jf "%F %T" "$START_DATETIME" +"%F %T" 2> /dev/null)

   if [[ "$TEST_DATETIME" != "$START_DATETIME" ]]
   then
      report_error_and_exit "'$START_DATETIME' is not a valid date/time value. $OSTYPE"
   fi
fi

echo "The date/time is valid."
```

I tested this script on a Red Hat-based system, a Debian-based system and OSX, and it worked as expected on all three platforms.  I did not have time to test on Windows (Cygwin).

Answer (score 4):

The `date` command will parse a date given with the `-d` argument.  If the date is invalid, an error message is printed to STDERR and `date` exits with an error status.   If the date is valid, it prints the date on STDOUT and exits with a success status.

Because of this, `date -d "$date"` can be used directly in a `bash` `if` statement.

The first wrinkle is that to prevent printing a message for valid dates, you need to redirect STDOUT to `/dev/null` using `>/dev/null`.

The second wrinkle is that `date` accepts an empty string as a valid date without complaint. In most cases, that should mean that your user didn't enter a date when they should have.  You will want to test for an empty date separately using the test `[ "z$date" != "z" ]`

`date` also accepts a variety of formats.  If you are using actual `bash` (as opposed to `dash` or some of ther `sh` variety, you could use regular expressions against your preferred format in place of a simple check for an empty string.  For example to check my preferred ISO format, I would use:  `[[ "$date" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]`

```
date=2001-01-01
if [ "z$date" != "z" ] && date -d "$date" >/dev/null
then
  echo "VALID DATE"
fi
```

If you try this with an invalid date (such as `2001-01-53`), it doesn't get into the `if` and it prints out:

> date: invalid date ‘2001-01-53’

Alternately, you could check if the date is invalid and exit:

```
date=2001-01-01
if [ "z$date" == "z" ]
then
  echo "No date specified"
  exit 1
fi
if ! [[ "$date" =~ ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$ ]]
then
  echo "Expected date in YYYY-MM-DD format"
  exit 1
fi
if ! date -d "$date" >/dev/null
then
  exit 1
fi
echo "VALID DATE"
```

Answer (score 2):

case statements make it easy to support multiple formats and capturing date-parts, i.e.

```
 case ${date} in
    [0-3][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] )
       yr=...
       mn=...
       dy=... 
    ;;
    [0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] )
       yr=...
       dy=... 
       mn=...
    ;;
    .... other formats
    ;;
    * )
      echo "ERROR on date format, from value=$date, expected formats ..."
      return 1
    ;;     
 esac
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strptime()` function available in Python's [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) or [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) modules or Perl's [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing) module.