# Bash validate date

Tags: linux, bash, macos, validation, date

I'm writing a shell script and am confused as to why my date validation code is not working. I tried the following solutions to similar questions I found, but is_valid is always set to 1:

```
date "+%m/%d/%Y" -d "$1" 2>1 > /dev/null
//or..
date -d "2012-02-29" > /dev/null 2>&1
is_valid=$?
#always set to 1, even when given a valid date
```

How do I correctly validate the date format? The date should only be valid if in the format MM/DD/YYYY

I also tried this solution: [Linux Bash - Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152759/linux-bash-date-format) but it always rejected the date as well.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the same result. When I run `date -d "2012-02-29 > /dev/null 2>&1" then "echo $?" I get `0`.

Comment: What does `date --version` print for you? (BTW, I get the same result as mbratch and Aleksey Izmailov.)

Comment: It prints: "date: illegal option -- - \n usage: date ....." I'm using Mac OSX btw

Comment: As you've now found out, Mac OS X is not Linux, and the GNU extensions don't necessarily work on non-Linux machines. The difficulty, sometimes, is determining when something is an extension.

Comment: BTW, `MM/DD/YYYY` is a very poorly chosen date format -- it's quite ambiguous with `DD/MM/YYYY`. Using `YYYY-MM-DD` sorts properly and is RFC-compliant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BSD `date` that ships with Mac OS X doesn't support the `-d` option (or rather, it uses `-d` for something entirely different). Either install GNU `date`, or use the following to validate your input string:

```
date -f "%Y-%m-%d" -j "2012-02-29" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `-f` provides the input format, and the `-j` tells `date` to simply output the date, not attempt to set the system clock.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this little function:

```
function isDateInvalid()
{
  date -d "$1" "+%m/%d/%Y" > /dev/null 2>&1
  res=$?
  echo "$res"
}

isDateInvalid "2012-02-219"
1

isDateInvalid "2012-02-29"
0
```

Comment: there is nothing in between those lines. I actually  an echo $? command right after, and it always prints 1

Answer (score 0):

```
for y in {2013..2014}; do
  for m in {01..12}; do
    for d in {01..31}; do
      [[ ! "`date -jf %Y%m%d $y$m$d +%Y%m%d`" = "$y$m$d" ]] && continue
      echo $y.$m.$d
    done
  done
done
```

if strings match, loop will proceed ...