# Validating Input in using Shell Script

Tags: shell

I have an input which will be given by an user and I have to check whether it a date type or not ? How can I do it using shell script ? If it is of date type then one command will execute otherwise another will execute .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221562/bash-validate-date might help you with validation of date

Comment: @RanganRoy: Please also read about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My question was how so compare two dates in shell script , two dates are stored into two varriables and that dates can be of any format . Sorry for the previous inconvenience ...