# How to accept date time combination in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to accept date time value from passing parameters through user and wants to validate that in shell script. How I can do that, I have tried in following way but failed:

```
./program.sh 12-10:12:11     (In this 12 is date and other is time)
```

I am passing this as parameter and accepting it in shell script

```
dtime=$1

if ! [ "`date '+%d-%H:%M:%S' -d $dtime 2>/dev/null`" = "$dtime" ]
then
echo $dtime is NOT a valid date format, use the d-H:M:S format
exit 0
fi

echo $dtime
```

But it's showing date is not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731346/validate-date-format-in-a-shell-script or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221562/bash-validate-date

Comment: BTW, there are quoting issues here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: i have tried this one also but not working

Comment: you're defeating your ability to debug by sending `date` output to `2>/dev/null`. Try `dtime=$1 ; date '+%d-%H:%M:%S' -d "$dtime"; echo status=$?` and if you get the processing you expect. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the format supplied to `date` command controls only the output, not the input (passed with the `--date` option). One needs to supply some format which `date` will understand. For example, one could manually replace the dash in the input with a space, prepend the current year/month and use this modified string for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#date/time string is passed as first argument
dtime=$1

#replace first occurrence of - in $dtime with space
#and prepend the current year/month/
#This will for example
#transform the input "12-10:12:11" to "2017/03/12 10:12:11", i.e.,
#into a format which `date` understands. The reason for this is
#to provide complete date specification, otherwise `date`
#would complain that the date is invalid.  
s=$(date +'%Y/%m/')${dtime/-/ }

#feed the transformed input obtained in previous step to the
#`date` command and print the output in the required '%d-%H:%M:%S' format
x=$(date +'%d-%H:%M:%S' --date="$s" 2> /dev/null)

#finally, check if this formatted value equals the original input or not
if [ "${x}" != "${dtime}" ]
then
    echo "$dtime is NOT a valid date format, use the d-H:M:S format"
    exit 0
fi

echo $dtime
```

Comment: tnx lot its working fine

Comment: Sir i want to add month also, then how i can do this ?

Comment: @jhon and what is your input format?

Comment: sir the above your code is working fine for me but i am not able to understand this code. Can you please give me the explaination of this code dtime=$1
s=$(date +'%Y/%m/')${dtime/-/ }

x=$(date +'%d-%H:%M:%S' --date="$s" 2> /dev/null)

if [ "${x}" != "${dtime}" ]
then
    echo "$dtime is NOT a valid date format, use the d-H:M:S format"
    exit 0
fi

echo $dtime

Comment: @jhon I have included additional comments - I hope this explains the script better...

Comment: Very very tnx sir

Comment: Sir i have accepted the date time format in this way  
sir  ./program.sh 2016-08-01 00:00:00 from the user .  Now  in script i want to divide this value such as date in another variable and time in another variable

Comment: @jhon then it's even simpler because this is a format `date` understands. You can just use `s="${dtime}"` and then `x=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --date="$s" 2> /dev/null)`. The rest would stay the same.

Comment: no not like that, i have acceppted date and time in this format ./program.sh 2016-08-01_00:00:00     and now i want to separte the date and time value in script.

Comment: @jhon ok, in that case `s=${dtime/_/ }` and `x=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S' --date="$s" 2> /dev/null)`

Comment: or if you want to use the date/time later, you can do `datePart=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d' --date="$s")`. This will save the date into a variable `datePart`. One can proceed similarly for the time...