# String comparison in bash is not working

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I'm new to bash scripting. Just wrote this simple program but it is throwing error.

```
#!/bin/bash
os=`uname -o`
echo $os
if ["$os"=="GNU/Linux"] ; then
    echo "Linux"
else
    echo "Windows"
fi
```

Using == or -eq for both cases I'm getting the following error and it is printing the else condn.

**./ostype.sh: line 3: [GNU/Linux==GNU/Linux]: No such file or directory**

**Windows**

Bash version : GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

Comment: This question has already been answered, see this link [1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script

Comment: With the proper spacing `=` and `==` should both work to compare strings.   `-eq` is an integer compare.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try

```
if [ "$os" = "GNU/Linux" ]
```

note the spaces, and the single `=`.

`[` is actually a program, and the rest are arguments!

Comment: +1 for `[ is actually a program, and the rest are arguments!`.. Many people do not know it. Even I didn't know few months ago. :-)

Comment: and for all intents and purposes you probably want to use the shell builtin `[[`, which is probably faster.

Comment: Oh... I thought, `[` is also overridden by shell built-in. just like `[[` & `echo`...

Answer (score 17):

Use `=` for string comparison. See: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Also, there should be a space around the square brackets and the comparison operator, i.e.

```
if [ "$os" = "GNU/Linux" ]; then 
  ^ ^     ^ ^           ^  
  | |     | |           |
   \-\-----\-\-----------\-- (need spaces here)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [[ "$os" == "GNU/Linux" ]]