# Conditional Postinstall Script

Tags: macos, installation, packagemaker

I'm creating a mpkg for OS X 10.6 - OS X 10.9. I want to create a post-install script that checks the OS version and runs a command based on the result

My pseudo code is:

```
if the OS version is equal to or less than 10.6.8 then
--command A--
else
--command B--
fi
exit 0
```

I'd be grateful for any help you can offer.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

You can get the OS version with `sw_vers -productVersion` -- that'll print something like "10.8.5". However, this may not be straightforward to compare. When Apple releases the successor to Mavericks, it'll probably be numbered 10.10, and "10.10" is textually *less than* "10.6.8" (because "1" < "6"). You could parse the version string into its components and compare elements numerically (see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format)), but that's rather messy.

It's probably easier to check the Darwin version with `uname -r` -- that'll print something like "12.5.0", which actually does correspond to the OS version, but in a [nontrivial way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)#Release_history):

- Darwin 10.x = OS X 10.6.x (and iOS 4)
- Darwin 11.x = OS X 10.7.approxamatelyx (and iOS 5)
- Darwin 12.x = OS X 10.8.approxamatelyx
- Darwin 13.x = OS X 10.9.x (and iOS 6)
- Darwin 14.x = iOS 7

... but that's actually easier for major version comparison, since you can just look at the first number to get the major version:

```
darwin_version=$(uname -r)
if (( ${darwin_version%%.*} < 11 )); then  # %%.* removes the first period and everything following that
    # do OS X 10.6 stuff
else
    # do OS X 10.7-10.9 stuff
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. All I need is major version, like 10.6, I don't need the minor portion. I'll see how this works out for me.