# OSTYPE not available in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, sh, ubuntu-14.04

Currently I'm setting up a new system using the new Xubuntu trusty tahr.
I'm not very familiar with shell scripting, but I have one which needs the OSTYPE environment variable to determine what to do.

If I call `echo $OSTYPE` in the xfce-terminal I get succesfully `linux-gnu`.

If I call following script I only get an empty line.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $OSTYPE
```

Am I missing something or is it maybe a problem of the new ubuntu?

On another machine of mine it works with that script. But I don't know if something was changed for that, because the system was originally not mine.

Comment: It is more portable to retrieve that information via `uname`.  eg `uname -o`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `OSTYPE` environment variable is not recognized by the original Bourne shell, which is what is being invoked by the first line of your script.

Replace it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

as appropriate to your setup.

Comment: I should have added that on my other machine it runs with /bin/sh. The other machine is using Ubuntu 13.10, but may have been altered without my knowledge.

Comment: In the end this was the hint in the correct direction. On my working machine /bin/sh was linked to /bin/bash . On the fresh installation /bin/sh is linked to /bin/dash

Comment: for portability: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: ^ just a note..bash is not (for portability). as newer ubuntu uses dash for shell. if you need some better portability, ensure its bourne shell POSIX compliant . In bash you can enforce compliancy using "set -o posix" or running script with --posix . REF - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode