# OS X's bash script can't use --color=auto

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I'm new to OS X and also other Linux distributions(Ubuntu, CentOS, RHEL) user.

I want to know why OS X's bash can not use `--color=auto` option and how to enable it.

I often use `ls --color=auto`, but on OS X, it doesn't work. The following is the command output:

```
$ ls --color=auto
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

I also read man page of `ls`, and I found `ls -G` is enabler of colorized output.
So, at this time, it's okay, but I'm a little bit annoying because I'm sharing the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` for all my linux environments.

Does anyone know these bash's different? And do you have any good idea to share the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` between OS X and some linux distributions without additional edit on each environment.

P.S.
My friend tells me bash on AIX(Linux server IBM version? I'm not sure) could not run `ls --color=auto` also.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/394247/3591528) uses os detection to alias color `ls`.

Comment: ls on macOS isn't bash, it's a command from a derivative of BSD UNIX.

Comment: @teppic I also use ls alias, but did not know `$platform` variable, thank you!

Comment: @clearlight I tried to run `ps -p $$` and I got `47232 ttys000    0:00.45 -bash`, but you mean it's not bash itself, it is a command from that?! Thank you give me a clue, I'll search and check with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of `ls` command and other commands like `ps` and `top` is different, most utils have a GNU version and BSD version. Linux take the GNU version while OSX may take a BSD version, so options for those commands may differ.

if you want to make a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` that works everywhere, you should judge the environment before you alias your command like:

```
_myos="$(uname)"

case $_myos in
  Linux) alias ls='ls --color';;
  Darwin) alias ls='ls -G';;
  *) ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ran the command and it says `Darwin`! I'll add this for my `.bashrc`. Thank you.

Comment: so basically a variation of the answer at the link provided by @teppic as the first comment reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `homebrew` to install GNU `coreutils`：

```
brew install coreutils
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

useful link：https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/966