# base64 doesnt have -w option in Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, base64

I am trying to use base64 but the script doesn't run successfully in Ubuntu machine

```
MYCOMMAND=$(base64  commands.sh)
```

So in Ubuntu , I have to use

```
MYCOMMAND=$(base64 -w0 commands.sh)
```

unfortunately this option is not there in Mac. How can i write a single script which runs both in Mac and Ubuntu

Comment: Maybe use a PHP one-liner which calls `base64_encode()` on its argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that works in both Linux and MacOS is to use `tr`:

```
MYCOMMAND=$(base64 commands.sh | tr -d '\n')
```

Answer (score 96):

Yes, the default macOS `base64` implementation doesn't have the `-w` flag. What does that flag do?

> ```
> -w, --wrap=COLS
> ```
>
> Wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76). Use 0 to disable line wrapping.

And here's the macOS man page for `base64`:

> ```
> -b count
> --break=count
> ```
>
> Insert line breaks every count characters. Default is 0, which generates an unbroken stream.

So, the flag is called `-b` in macOS, and it already defaults to `0`, which means `base64` in macOS has the same behaviour as `base64 -w0` on Linux. You'll have to detect which platform you run on to use the appropriate variation of the command. See here: [Detect the OS from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394230/476); the platform name you're looking for for macOS is "Darwin".

Answer (score 14):

In Mac's it's `-b`, and the default is already 0.

```
$ man base64
...
OPTIONS
     The following options are available:
     -b count
     --break=count        Insert line breaks every count characters. Default is 0, which generates an unbroken stream.
...
```

One way to have the script work for both is checking for errors:

```
MYCOMMAND=$(base64 -w0 commands.sh)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  MYCOMMAND=$(base64 commands.sh)
fi
```

You can also run an explicit test, e.g

```
echo | base64 -w0 > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # GNU coreutils base64, '-w' supported
  MYCOMMAND=$(base64 -w0 commands.sh)
else
  # Openssl base64, no wrapping by default
  MYCOMMAND=$(base64 commands.sh)
fi
```