# ddev get drud/ddev-platformsh configuration - error when generating needed environment variables on MacOS

Tags: ddev, platform.sh

I'm encountering an issue with undefined project variables following the installation steps outlined here: https://github.com/drud/ddev-platformsh#install

Steps 1-3 were smooth, with no issues.

On step 4 `ddev get drud/ddev-platformsh`, the script runs successfully until the 'Executing post-install actions:' section. Here is the output with a few preceding lines for context:

```
Configuration complete. You may now run 'ddev start'.


Installing project-level components:
 web-build/Dockerfile.platformsh
 homeadditions/.bashrc.d/platformsh-environment.sh
 platformsh/.gitignore
 platformsh/generate_db_relationship.sh
 platformsh/generate_elasticsearch_relationship.sh
 platformsh/generate_memcached_relationship.sh
 platformsh/generate_redis_relationship.sh

Installing global components:
 commands/web/platform

Executing post-install actions:
 Support composer and python3 dependencies
BASE64_ENCODE=base64 -w 0
base64: illegal option -- w
base64: illegal option -- w

 Installing dependencies and generating needed environment variables
could not process post-install action (2) 'Installing dependencies and generating needed environment variables'
```

How do I address this? The issue could be that I'm running this on MacOS, which doesn't support the -w flag for BASE64 ([based on this other SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463027/base64-doesnt-have-w-option-in-mac)).

Also, I see that Platform has these environment variables: https://docs.platform.sh/development/variables/use-variables.html#use-platformsh-provided-variables
...but I'm unclear how/where they should be integrated into the DDEV config files.

Also, after encountering the config error, I ran this command, which failed and further indicated that at least one project variable was missing:

```
$ ddev drush cr

In Config.php line 567:

  The appDir variable is not defined. Are you sure you're running on Platform.sh?

Failed to run drush cr: exit status 1
```

Any advice wrt how to overcome this issue would be welcome. Thank you.

My environment:
DDEV: v1.21.4
OS: MacOS Ventura 13.1
CPU: Apple M1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on macOS and you have the homebrew version of base64 installed. Unfortunately, it's quite different in its behavior. Could you please uninstall the homebrew version? `brew uninstall base64 && hash -r` (`hash -r` just makes the changes in PATH immediately effective).

See https://github.com/drud/ddev-platformsh/issues/93