# Syntax issues in OS detection

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I'm working on a script using bash to determine the os being used and print to the screen the version.

The only line giving me issues is this one, could you please help me?:

Comment: Please state the exact error message. *"I was told it has a syntax issue..."* is not a good problem statement. Also see [Detect the OS from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394230/608639)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use

```
lsb_release -d
```

for getting the distribution name, or

```
lsb_release -a
```

to get all info about the distro.

More info about this [linux standard base utility](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have spaces between the two sides of the `=` sign, and you need to execute the right side as a subcommand (using `$()` syntax).

```
current_os=$(cat /etc/*-release | grep CentOS)
```

With spaces like `current_os = ...` bash will interpret it as you trying to run a command called `current_os`.

Comment: Great! I tried this and it printed the correct os name on centos.  When I run this command on Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

Comment: @think - you'll need to post the contents of your script for help with that.

Comment: @think: you probably have windows line endings in your script. `dos2unix` can fix that.

Comment: @think - Mat is likely correct and you may have line-endings that are causing problems. Run `dos2unix os-script.txt` and try again.

Comment: Okay, I believe my ubuntu VM needs an internet connection to run dos2unix, which it doesn't right now. I'll try.

Comment: @think `sed -i 's/.$//' os-script.txt` should do it as well, and your system should already have `sed` installed.

Comment: @think are you in the same directory as `os-script.txt`? Otherwise provide the full path to it.

Comment: I went to the correct directory before typing in sed.  I think it took it, but I'm still getting syntax errors for this:          function CurrentOs(){

Comment: @think ah I see it now - `function name()` is not valid bash syntax for declaring functions. Either use the `function name { }` format, or `name () { }` format.

Comment: Great, it fixed line 1 issue. I changed to just this: CurrentOs() {}                                   There is an issue somewhere with my if, elif, or else statements, because it will print that the os is Centos on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with my if statement?                                                  if(CurrentOs=$"CentOS Linux"); then {}

Comment: @think shouldn't it be `if [[ $CurrentOS = "CentOS Linux ]]; then ...`? Also, since it seems you have other problems now, I'd recommend opening a separate question and including the contents of your entire script in the question and asking what's causing your syntax issues. It would be a lot easier for you to get help rather than ask in comments. It would also let people see your entire script and possibly point out extra problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
source /etc/os-release
current_os=$PRETTY_NAME
```

or if you don't want to pull everything in

```
current_os=$(source /etc/os-release && echo $PRETTY_NAME)
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the commands in backticks (``) and the statement will assign the output of the command.

```
current_os=`cat /etc/*-release | grep CentOS`
```

Comment: Syntax still invalid, and backticks are not recommended, `$()` is better

Comment: $() will give you exactly the same result in this case, so it's not better, it's just another solution.

Comment: It's better advice in general.

Comment: Backticks are considered obsolete, as they are harder to read and much harder to nest.