# Determining current OS using programmatic ways

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

I have a dual boot machine (windows/ubuntu) and I need to automate the toggle between them, so first I need to check on which OS am I right now in programmatic way
(background: there will be 2 different tasks that will reach the machine from remote, each designed for their specific OS - linux or windows - and so I'll need to restart accordingly).

Is there a good way to do so other then look for a predefined anchor file/path ?

Comment: You should state the language you are working with. This is usually a scripting task so... possible duplicate of [How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: There is no specific language - as long as it works. Main problem in scripting is adjusting the script to the OS (e.g run .sh in linux and .bat in windows) - when it's unknown

Comment: You can use the same bash script on linux and windows, if you install cygwin on your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C preprocessor to identify the OS, something liḱe in your translation unit can help you.

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    //linux 
#elif _WIN32
    //windows 
#elif _MACH__
   //Mac
#else

#endif
```