# How can i launch jenkins in browser automatically with script

Tags: linux, unix, docker, jenkins, command

I have installed  Jenkins using docker.Albeit, I have skipped the manual setup.
when I build the image and run it(still I have many things to do), I need to type IP and port on my browser to open Jenkins dashboard.

**My question is ,can I automate, with the script, in docker that  Jenkins which is built should open in the browser when I run that image?**

any commands need to run please comment it

I tried to open browser via command, but it end up with error. 
Anyone help with my automation tool.

Thank you in advance

Comment: which Host os u are using?

Comment: is worked for u? its working if yes the accept it

Comment: @Adiii im working on windows, base os is ubuntu 14.04.. actually i need to do it dynamically, it shoud work on different system...Help me with this

sorry for late comment, i was working on ur solution only :)

Comment: check os and run different command base on os

Comment: actually i wanted to execute on different IP and different username   will try and update u shortly.. thank u @Adiii

Comment: i accept ur solution. i reframe my question and post with code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167388/discussion-between-hithesh-and-adiii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your wifi information and get your system. For example, your HOST IP is 192.168.1.1 using `ifconfig or ipconfig` and user name by `whoami` then inside container you can do like

`ssh user_name@192.168.1.1 'DISPLAY=:0 firefox http://192.168.1.1:8080'`

for linux based.

I f host is window then you can run

```
ssh user_name@192.168.1.1 'DISPLAY=:0 start http://192.168.1.1:8080'
```

if you want to avoid username and password just public-private key and place your public key in container and ssh using that key.

or `docker exec -it container_name ash|bash -c ssh user_name@192.168.1.1 'DISPLAY=:0 firefox http://192.168.1.1:8080'`

You can run different command base on os

```
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
        # ...
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
        # Mac OSX
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "cygwin" ]]; then
        # POSIX compatibility layer and Linux environment emulation for Windows
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "msys" ]]; then
        # Lightweight shell and GNU utilities compiled for Windows (part of MinGW)
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "win32" ]]; then
        # I'm not sure this can happen.
elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "freebsd"* ]]; then
        # ...
else
        # Unknown.
fi
```

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/logging-in-with-an-ssh-private-key-on-linuxmac/

[How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: i need to make it dynamic.. it should work for different system.