# Host key verification failed. in docker

Tags: unix, docker, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I wanted to launch the jenkins which is installed through docker automatically in browser.. im working on windows os. in docker base os is ubuntu.. then i used solution from this link[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422804/how-can-i-launch-jenkins-in-browser-automatically-with-script?noredirect=1#comment85854009_49422804).now im getting following error when i ssh using -v command i find that "read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address"

by going through many websites i have created ssh file through windows using gitbash it contains id_rsa,id_rsa.pub,known_hosts files.

Now what should i do to launch the jenkins file in browser which is build using docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to address the error message you pasted for now.

`ssh` is trying to get keyboard input for the passphrase on your private key, but can't open the terminal correctly. Are you running the `ssh` command directly in the terminal, or from a script? If not, try running `ssh` directly. If you need to run `ssh` from a script:

1. Maybe try with keys that don't have a passphrase.
2. If you can use `ssh-agent`: Run `eval $(ssh-agent)`, then run `ssh-add` and enter your passphrase. `ssh` will no longer prompt for a passphrase now.

Comment: i will try to create ssh using script in docker, and copy my windows pub key to it(this is my idea) will it work???? @sneep

Comment: i created ssh using git bash in my win machine... now i need to make it run automatically on my docker which basic os in ubuntu 14.04. then i will copy my win ssh public key to docker machine ssh to make it run... will it work is my question @sneep

Comment: I think that sounds more or less okay

Comment: Thank you, can anything made to make it effective??? any links?? @sneep

Comment: i have changed idea..i need to create user from docker and through that user i create .ssh folder there i need to place my host machine pub key(windows)... which file i need to use to place pub key??????

Comment: There should be a file called `id_rsa.pub`. That's your public key.

Comment: where should i place that id_rsa.pub key? @sneep

Comment: You put the contents of `id_rsa.pub` into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (if it doesn't exist yet, you have to create it) on the machine you want to login to