# What to put for NPM scripts when developers are on multiple systems?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I have a web app project, and it uses Mongo, so one of my NPM scripts is `"start-mongo-dev": "mongod"`, for spinning up the Mongo daemon during development.

I used to use OSX, but just got a new computer and run Linux Ubuntu. Now the command to begin the daemon is `sudo service mongod start`, so it would seem I should change the NPM script to that.

But that is a red flag. What if I go back to the old computer at all? What if I collaborate on this project with someone who uses OSX?

In short, how is one expected to handle developing with multiple OS's?

Comment: One option is to stick with things that can be installed as Node modules and then just run those commands since they _should_ work cross-platform without issue.

Answer (score 3):

Ian's solution may be better but one alternative would be to create a bash script inside your project that detects the OS and runs the appropriate command. You can find more info on how to do that here [How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

In some packages, I see divisions like this indicated with a `:`. For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start-mongo-dev:osx": "mongod",
  "start-mongo-dev:ubuntu": "sudo service mongod start"
}
```

I am not aware of a canonical solution, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. I happen to like this one, though. #opinion