# How to detect OS and load ZSH settings conditionally?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use several different OS's at home and work and I want to be able to load platorm-specific ZSH settings conditionally, depending on which OS I'm using at the given moment.

I tried this but it doesn't load everything I expect:

```
# Condtitional loading of zsh settings per platform

if command apt > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/debian.zsh

elif command systemctl > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/systemd.zsh

elif command freebsd-version > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/freebsd.zsh

elif [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]]; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/mac.zsh

elif command kubectl > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/kubernetes.zsh

else
    echo 'Unknown OS!'
fi
```

What is the best way to do this detection and what I'm doing wrong?
I know this approach of mine doesn't work as when I run `zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE`, it doesn't show all desired files sourced.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably `/etc` is unique to each OS; just add an environment variable to `/etc/zshenv` that identifies the current OS, and check that variable in your configuration.

Comment: @chepner which part of /etc you'd target?

Comment: `/etc/zshenv`. A lot of what's in `/etc` is OS-specific (or at least distribution-specific), so I'm assuming you aren't sharing the same directory between OS installs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394230/608639)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Revised Answer (2020-Feb-09)

Thanks to @Cyberbeni for reminding me that `apt` on macOS would incorrectly match the system Java runtime's **A**nnotation **P**rocessing **T**ool. Rolling up the necessary changes, we now have:

```bash
# What OS are we running?
if [[ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]]; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM"/os/mac.zsh

elif command -v freebsd-version > /dev/null; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM"/os/freebsd.zsh

elif command -v apt > /dev/null; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM"/os/debian.zsh

else
    echo 'Unknown OS!'
fi

# Do we have systemd on board?
if command -v systemctl > /dev/null; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM"/os/systemd.zsh
fi

# Ditto Kubernetes?
if command -v kubectl > /dev/null; then
    source "$ZSH_CUSTOM"/os/kubernetes.zsh
fi
```

### Original answer

I answered exactly the same question on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/aosx89/how_to_detect_os_and_load_zsh_settings/eg3hqz6/), so to close the loop, here's what I wrote:

Your current logic literally says that, for instance, a Debian system cannot possibly run systemd or Kubernetes, which is clearly untrue. That's exactly what `if...elif...else...fi` implements: *mutual exclusivity*.

It looks to me like only the OS-specific tests need to be mutually exclusive, so you're probably looking at something like:

```bash
# What OS are we running?
if command apt > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/debian.zsh

elif command freebsd-version > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/freebsd.zsh

elif [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]]; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/mac.zsh

else
    echo 'Unknown OS!'
fi

# Do we have systemd on board?
if command systemctl > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/systemd.zsh
fi

# Ditto Kubernetes?
if command kubectl > /dev/null; then
    source $ZSH_CUSTOM/os/kubernetes.zsh
fi
```

UPDATE: Actually, I didn't look closely enough at your code, and you're also calling `command` wrong. All your invocations should be of the form:

```
if command -v <cmd_name> > /dev/null
```

which returns success if `<cmd_name>` is found in your `PATH`. `command <cmd_name>` actually **runs** `<cmd_name>` and returns its exit status, which can return a *failure* exit code (i.e. false negative) due to lack of appropriate arguments.

Comment: macOS 13.1 also has apt preinstalled (although when you try to run `apt --help` or similar, it just complains that there is no Java Runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Verifying an OS is system dependent. You can use the package managers to verify a certain distribution, but this not desired, since there are certainly other distributions which the same package manager as well.

You can try to use [lsb_release](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/lsb_release.1.html) and grep on the correct distribution. Or use [uname](http://www.linfo.org/uname.html).

Which OS'es do not load in your script, and which do?

Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)

Comment: Try to use lsb_release or uname with some flags in your script to verify the distribution.