# How to find and replace string in a file WITHOUT sed

Tags: shell

This is for my setup repo which I use in fresh linux installs and company provided macbooks. I have this makefile target:

```
omz-theme:
    sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME=".*"/ZSH_THEME="$(THEME)"/g' $(HOME)/.zshrc
```

This works fine on linux but breaks on macs because they use BSD's `sed`. I need some way to find and replace text in my `.zshrc` that will run regardless of the system. Almost all resources online point only to sed.

Edit: This is how it "breaks" on mac. Doesn't happen if I do `brew install gnu-sed` and change the target to use `gsed`

```
sed: 1: "/Users/username/.zshrc": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Comment: How does it break, exactly? (Please [edit] your question to explain).  Does it work if you simply use `sed -i '' ...`?

Comment: The "unterminated substitute pattern" error is not a reason you can't use sed, it's a reason you can't use `/` in your sed expression. If you use something like `@` that doesn't exist in your filename it'll be fine.

Comment: ...that said, for a very good general-purpose reference with a number of options that don't use `sed`, see [BashFAQ #21](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for find and replace as well.   [Here's a resource with more detail.](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/find-replace-text-in-file#search-replace-awk).

For example, your makefile command could be replaced with:

```
omz-theme:
    awk -v var="ZSH_THEME=$(echo THEME)" '{sub(/^ZSH_THEME=.*$/, var); print}' $(HOME)/.zshrc
```

You could use this to overwrite the existing `$(HOME)/.zshrc` file using redirection:

```
omz-theme:
    awk -v var="ZSH_THEME=$(echo THEME)" '{sub(/^ZSH_THEME=.*$/, var); print}' $(HOME)/.zshrc > $(HOME)/.zshrc
```

Alternately, you could [check the OS using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script) `OSTYPE` and then use the correct `sed` syntax for BSD and GNU:

```
omz-theme:
    if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu"* ]]; then 
        sed -i 's/ZSH_THEME=".*"/ZSH_THEME="$(THEME)"/g' $(HOME)/.zshrc
    else
        sed -i '' 's/ZSH_THEME=".*"/ZSH_THEME="$(THEME)"/g' $(HOME)/.zshrc
    fi
```

(note: I didn't test the above, but you get the idea)